# Use android keystore file in Mac and Windows

Tags: android, android-keystore

My client asked me to update the Android app which is available on Google PlayStore.
The previous version was built in Mac, and Keystore file was also generated in Mac.
Unfortunately, I don't have Macintosh. There is only a PC with Windows 7.

Is it possible to use the Keystore file, which is generated in Mac, in Windows?
Would you advise me what I should do?

Any help would be appreciated :D

Comment: You can use that same keystore into any OS to sign the application ..

Comment: Yes if you remember the public and private key password, they you can use that existing keystore file for signing.

Comment: yes you can use use same keystore.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! So I can publish the updated version to Google PlayStore without Mac, right?